# List of Current Folder files ONLY?

Tags: file, perforce, non-recursive

Hello I'm trying to get Perforce syntax to obtain (for example using "fstat") list of files only in given folder (depot), without rubbish from all sub-folders. But I was not able to find anything in the docs, nothing related when using Google, even experimenting with ".", ".../." etc. lead me to nowhere...

Is that because it's not possible at all? I can't understand why... Isn't that a performance back hit?!

Thanks in advance.
Seb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah finally.

It was partially my own fault - I'd set ExceptionLevel to ExceptionOnBothErrorsAndWarnings... I needed full debug... Unfortunately:

1. When exception was raised - there was no Response object created, and I could not read the warning message, which wasn't part of the exception message (or object).
2. Using '//depot/Folder1/Folderx/*' thrown warning "No such file(s)!" - what is not something that developer might expect... As not being any special case...

It seems that I have still much to learn on the Perforce though :-/

Thank you guys for your posting.
Seb.

Answer (score 3):

A single '*' expands to "all files in this directory" in p4 (no subdirectories).  So, e.g. at a Unix shell prompt, in the correct directory in a perforce client:

```
$ p4 fstat '*'
```

You need to quote or escape the `*` to avoid the *shell* expanding it, of course;-).

Comment: What if I want to specify it on the Prforce, so to list files from "//depot/Folder1/Folderx/" ? Shall I first go around and map depot folder to working folder, change PWD and THEN use "fstat"? I hoped there is more straightforward solution... (BTW: I'm working with p4.Net).

Comment: Did you try `p4 fstat '//depot/Folder1/Folderx/*'` ?

Comment: Yeah, as first try. Only to get this esoteric exception: "Error running Perforce command!". And got it with many combinations of ".", "...", directory with or without slash etc. Only "/..." executed properly...